# What should i do to apply datepicker to this code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe add to your question, what you have tried and what happened. Any errors you received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attributes to your property

`[DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}")]
 public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}`

and in your view

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate)`